# How to instantiate an Akka actor from a type parameter

Tags: scala, akka

I am scaffolding tests for an Akka application, where I wish to inject an actor to a test class:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.testkit.{ ImplicitSender, TestActors, TestKit }
import org.scalatest.{ BeforeAndAfterAll, Matchers, WordSpecLike }
import akka.actor.Props
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.event.Logging
import akka.actor.ActorRef

class Simulation[A <: SimulationActor : scala.reflect.ClassTag]
  extends TestKit(ActorSystem("AkkaSimulation")) with ImplicitSender
    with WordSpecLike with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll {

    override def afterAll {
      TestKit.shutdownActorSystem(system)
    }

   val invariantActor1 = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[A1]))
   val invariantActor2 = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[A2], invariantActor1))
   val actorUnderTest = system.actorOf(Props[SimulationActor]) // how to pass additional argument to Props here?


  // test logic here

}

// then elsewhere use the above template:
class Simulation1 extends Simulation[Sim1]
class Simulation2 extends Simulation[Sim2]
class Simulation extends Simulation[Sim3]
// and so on...
```

I experience the following benign problem with this design:

I am lost on passing an additional value argument to `Props`, when providing the type parameter A. Can't find a syntax that works for this case, coming to doubt that `Props` enables this use case in any simple way. The following line needs to pass an `ActorRef` argument, because `SimulationActor` expects one, but I can't find a way to pass it through. Is there an alternative actor instantiation form, that will allow both a type parameter for the actor type, and a value parameter for the actor's constructor?

```
val actorUnderTest = system.actorOf(Props[SimulationActor])
```

There appears to be no support for:

```
val actorUnderTest = system.actorOf(Props[SimulationActor], invariantActor2)
```

I'm reticent introducing Akka Typed at this stage; for pure elegance sake, it would be nice not changing the target actor to receive its value argument as a message after startup, which is otherwise the offhand workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if `Props` has no adequate constructor to use for this, so `ClassTag` to the rescue!

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class Simulation[A <: WorldSimulationActor : scala.reflect.ClassTag](implicit tag: ClassTag[A])

    .
    .
    .

  val actorUnderTestr = system.actorOf(Props(tag.runtimeClass, invariantActor2))
```

Voila. If something simpler is hiding in the [API](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/Props$.html) [docs](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/Props.html), I sure didn't spot it.